# My android game icon not utilising full allowed icon space in devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, photoshop, android-icons

My android game icon not utilizing full allowed icon space in devices; it's only 3/4th of the allowed space. I have been developing with Unity and provided all different icon sizes. I think the problem is with the psd file I created. Are there any guidelines or instructions for creating icons in Photoshop or Illustrator so that it will make an icon utilize the full icon space available on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Something to check when saving the psd file as an image is that it does not have any blank space around the icon. Make sure to crop any extra space.

Most likely, the problem is that you are providing an image file of the icon into only one of the drawable files. When run on a device, the icon is scaled down in steps multiple times until it fits in the desired area. The resulting image may be significantly smaller than the area provided.
To solve this, you should have a separate image in each of the four main drawable folders (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, & xxhdpi) with the exact size needed by each resolution device. If you are using Photoshop, you can do this by creating Smart Objects for each of the sizes.
This is shown very well in this Photoshop demonstration by Howard Pinsky:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhrgi_JfcYo.
You can also do the same thing manually with Photoshop or other image editing services, even including Paint.

As for using the right size for each resolution, the Android Developers website has information on finding the image pixel dimensions for each of the drawable folders.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html